# Multiple Monitors switch around when my xorg.conf is used

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

When in TwinView the system makes my Primary Display my BenQ 24" and my Samsung 32" TV the second screen, Great!

Trouble is: When I make a basic xorg.conf using NVIDIA-SETTINGS I reboot and it gets them backwards, the image that Ubuntu thinks is the BenQ primary (according to what All Settings > Displays & NVIDIA-SETTINGS both say) is actually showing on the TV, and the BenQ is showing a big grey screen, but the cursor works.

http://pastebin.com/aMiTzRqG

One final complication is that my TV runs through my AMP in order to get digital sound, it shows in Ubuntu as 'Onkyo blah..'. My Monitor is using the DisplayPort of my GeForce GTX 670 while the TV is on HDMI, this may be what's making the TV primary (as it carries the sound).

If I make another conf which disables the TV it reverts back to TwinView on reboot, here's the conf for that if its worth while:

http://pastebin.com/xiQmy29n

Help!

Comment: So, last week I managed to get a desktop background on the main display but I still cant drag windows over and the cursor is still a cross and no menus show except for right click. 

The "fix" applid using this patch: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/885989/comments/3 then using the instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217711/how-do-i-rebuild-and-test-nautilus-source using this cmd to apply the patch: cat /home/USER/Downloads/nautilus.patch | patch -p1

Comment: Also tired GNOME which as far as I can tell uses Metacity, not Nautilus (please correct me) but still the same issue.